# Write ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js

I watched some possible answers to my problem but I can't find a way to solve it.

When I call localhost:3000/users/create_account, I have an error ECONNRESET. 
It concerns this service:

```
router.post('/create_account', function (req, res, next) {
const results = [];
client.connect();

// Grab data from http request
const data = {
username: req.body.username, name: req.body.user,
firstname: req.body.firstname, email: req.body.email,
location: req.body.location
};

// Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
client.connect('error', function (err, data) {
// Handle connection errors
if (err) {
  done();
  console.log(err);
  return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: err });
}

const queryInsert = 'INSERT INTO Users(username, name,'
  + 'firstname, email, location) values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)';
const values = [data.username, data.name,
data.firstname, data.email, data.location];

// SQL Query > Insert Data into Users 
client.query(queryInsert, values, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
  } else {
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();

      Promise.all([queryInsert])
        .then(() => client.end()).catch(err => console.log(err));
      return res.json(results);
    });
  };
});
```

Is someone have an idea of what causes that and how to resolve this problem, please?

This is the complete error:

```
Error: write ECONNRESET
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:764:25)
at Socket._write (net.js:783:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:397:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:383:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
at Socket.write (net.js:707:40)
at Connection._send (C:\Users\Amaris\Desktop\NodeJS_Projects\basefugees-dev-backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:198:24)
at Connection.password (C:\Users\Amaris\Desktop\NodeJS_Projects\basefugees-dev-backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:190:8)
at C:\Users\Amaris\Desktop\NodeJS_Projects\basefugees-dev-backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:98:9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! basefugees-dev-backend@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www node`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the basefugees-dev-backend@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amaris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07- 11T14_05_26_893Z-debug.log
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "basefugees-dev-backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www node",
    "database": "node ./models/database",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pg": "^6.1.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post full error logs?

Comment: Its edited thanks !

Comment: Are you running it thru npm start? If yes, pls share package.json also

Comment: Where are you defining `query` in the line: `query.on(... `?  I don't see it defined, your error might be swallowing a simple error due to that not being in scope.

Comment: Yes thru npm start. Done

Comment: @paul oh yes i didn't see that. It's fixed but I still have the same issue though :/

Comment: Ok, but same thing with `client`, and likely others.  Are you posting all the relevant code?

Comment: Did you try running simple sql commands like `SELECT 1` to see if you are actually able to connect to postgres from node? I assume your error is happening in this line
`client.connect('error', function (err, data) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be following the correct API for error handling.  From the [docs](https://node-postgres.com/api/client), there is no overload of `client.connect()` that takes a string as the first parameter.  It may be attempting to use that value as a password or other config value based on the error stack.

What you want to use instead is:

```
client.on('error', (err) => { 
   // do whatever.  Though again you're calling a `done` that doesn't seem defined, and some other concerns. 
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah it's that ! Thanks for all. I'm kinda new into node.js so i'm still learning sorry :/